# Bootstrap: divs overlapping the jumbotron

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am a beginner in bootstrap and I have been experimenting with it to create a homepage for my website. The problem I am facing is this:

[image]

The three images are overlapping the jumbotron and I can't figure out why. The following is the HTML code:

```
<!--navigation bar-->
<div class="navbar-wrapper">


    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="logo" href="#"><img src="C:\Users\Mickey.Utopia\Documents\EdHoc\temp-logo.jpg" height= "50" width =  "80"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-right">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <!--
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          -->
            <li class = "animate"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href = "C:\Users\Mickey.Utopia\Documents\EdHoc\Sign_in.htm">Sign In</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Sign Up</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
</div>



<div class='jumbotron' >
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12" >
        <h1 id="jumb">Welcome to EdHoc. <br>Discover the best places to learn and collaborate with friends to make learning easier.</h1>
          </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-8 col-lg-8 col-sm-8" id="search">
                <!--Search Bar here-->
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search by location, institute, discipline" id="srcb">
                <!--Button-->
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4" id="button">
                  <a href="" class="btn btn-default">Go</a> 
              </div>
            </div>  
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>

      <div class="container marketing">

  <!-- Three columns of text below the jumbotron -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12 col-lg-4">
      <img class="img-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna.</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <img class="img-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh.</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <img class="img-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
  </div><!-- /.row -->

<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="\bootstrap-3.3.5-dist\bootstrap-3.3.5-dist\js\bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
<script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
```

The related CSS (apart from the bootstrap files):

```
.navbar {
background-color: transparent;
border: none;
}
.jumbotron {
height: 400px;
background-image: url(../images/woman.jpg);
background-size: cover;
border: none;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top:0;
z-index: -100; 
}

#jumb {
color: white;
font-size: 20px;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you developing locally or can you send a link to site as cant replicate in jsfiddle etc, could take a quick look in the inspector?

Comment: Please don't ask for urgent responses here - questions on Stack Overflow, and pretty much any place on the web, are answered by volunteers, and we regard all questions as equally important.

Comment: Open the Inspector, then right click on the grey circle and select inspect element. It should highlight what element that is in the html and troubleshoot from there. Could be this <img class="img-circle">?

Comment: @halfer i am also new at posting in stackoverflow. I'll keep your suggestions in mind. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @user3650571: I don't think being new here matters. Perhaps it is a cultural difference in your locality, but in my view, one cannot ask volunteers for urgency anywhere in the world,  either online or offline. I see this a lot here, and am quite perplexed by it. One can ask for urgency if one is paying for a freelancer.

Answer (score 1):

You have your `jumbotron` div using position:absolute which is why the content under it is overlapping. See the following references:

> **position: absolute;** An element with position: absolute; is positioned
>   relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned
>   relative to the viewport, like fixed).
>
> However; if an absolute positioned element has no positioned
>   ancestors, it uses the document body, and moves along with page
>   scrolling.
>
> Note: A "positioned" element is one whose position is anything except
>   static.

And

> **Overlapping Elements**
>   When elements are positioned, they can overlap
>   other elements.
>
> The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element (which
>   element should be placed in front of, or behind, the others).
>
> An element can have a positive or negative stack order:

[Absolute, Relative, Fixed Positioning: How Do They Differ?](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/)

*You also have some structural inconsistencies such as `col-sm-8 col-xs-12 col-lg-4` This makes little sense to place the smallest breakpoint size between to larger sizes: See [Grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed)

You should start by consulting the documentation as to how these components are structured and how they interact with one another. [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/)

```css
.navbar.navbar-custom {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
}
div.jumbotron {
  height: 400px;
  background-image: url(http://interiorofficesystems.com/wp-content/themes/ios/uploads/product_photo/afe3a3ed124cb421preview%20-%20114371%20-%20Tayco_View02.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  border: none;
}
div.jumbotron .jumb {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top navbar-custom">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
      <a class="logo" href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x50/266080/fff" height="50" width="80">
      </a>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="animate"><a href="#about">About</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="C:\Users\Mickey.Utopia\Documents\EdHoc\Sign_in.htm">Sign In</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class='jumbotron'>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="jumb">
      <h1>Welcome to EdHoc.</h1> 
      <br>
      <p>Discover the best places to learn and collaborate with friends to make learning easier.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
      <input type="text" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search by location, institute, discipline" id="srcb"> <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="button" type="button">Go!</button>
      </span>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img class="img-circle" src="http://placehold.it/200x200/000" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
      <h2>Heading</h2>

      <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna.</p> <a class="btn btn-default"
      href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img class="img-circle" src="http://placehold.it/200x200/000" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
      <h2>Heading</h2>

      <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh.</p> <a class="btn btn-default"
      href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img class="img-circle" src="http://placehold.it/200x200/000" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
      <h2>Heading</h2>

      <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
      <a
      class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Your changes solved the initial problem, although it has brought on a new issue. Removing the "position: absolute" causes the jumbotron to be placed below the navigation bar but i want the navbar to overlap the jumbotron. How would i go on doing that if i remove the absolute property?

Comment: I don't see that issue in the answer I posted yesterday, it was that way initially then I referred back the to image you posted and changed it so the image is under the navbar, not below, See Snippet again.